# Passing parameters to nested function in coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript, casperjs

Function 'start' passes the username and the password to the function logIn. Problem is i get:

'ReferenceError: Can't find variable: username'

The problem ocurse at the end of the snippet. At the second and third '@echo' of the snippet the variable 'username' is shown correctly.

Question is: How can i pass the parameter username and password further to the nested functions?

Snippet:

```
logIn = (username, password) ->
        @echo '--- LogIn ---'
        @echo '--- KNOWN HERE = ' + username + " ---"
        @then ->
            @echo '--- username KNOWN HERE = ' +  username + ' ---'
            @evaluate ->
                  @echo '--- @evaluate username NOT KNOWN HERE = ' + username + ' ---'
```

Full code:

```
    casper = require('casper').create({
        clientScripts: ["includes/jquery.min.js"],
        verbose: true,
        logLevel: 'debug'
})

    logIn = (username, password) ->
        @echo '--- LogIn ---'
        @echo '--- '+username+' // '+password+" ---"
        @then ->
            @echo '--- username in do = ' +  username + ' ---'
            @evaluate ->
                @echo '--- @evaluate username = ' + username + ' ---'
                $('#id_email').val(username)
                $('#id_password').val(password)
                $('.AuthForm').submit()

    start = -> 
        @start loginURL
        @echo '--- accounts.length = ' + accounts.length + ' ---'
        logIn.call @, accounts[currentAccount][0], accounts[currentAccount][1]
```

Comment: Perhaps you mixed tabs and spaces? Try converting tabs to spaces, then see if that line is still nested within `logIn`.

Comment: i tried that but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that [Casper#evaluate](http://casperjs.org/#phantom_Casper_evaluate) runs the given function *in the page that you're testing*. That page doesn't have access to the `username` and `password` variables from your test script unless you pass them in. The solution is to change

```
@evaluate ->
  ...
```

to

```
@evaluate ((username, password) ->
  ...
), {username, password}
```